# Game Center Calling Leaderboard function not responding?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, game-center

I am calling the leader board like this:

```
-(void)viewscores:(SPEvent*)event
{  

    GKLeaderboardViewController *leaderboardController = [[GKLeaderboardViewController alloc] init];      
    if (leaderboardController != nil) {  
        leaderboardController.leaderboardDelegate = self;  

        UIWindow* window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;  
        [window addSubview: self.rootViewController];  
        [self presentModalViewController: leaderboardController animated: YES];  

    }     
}
```

When I Click the leader board button, I receive an error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[UIViewController presentModalViewController:animated:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x3e2fc7f8'
```

Is this normal?

Comment: in what file are you using this method ?

Comment: I am calling this in my Game.m File

Answer (score 2):

You should probably call the function in a viewController. In one of my app's the code looks like this:

```
-(IBAction)showLeaderBoard {

    GKLeaderboardViewController *leaderBoardCont = [[GKLeaderboardViewController alloc] init];
    if (leaderBoardCont) {
        leaderBoardCont.category=@"1S";
        leaderBoardCont.timeScope=GKLeaderboardTimeScopeWeek;
        leaderBoardCont.leaderboardDelegate=self;
        [self presentModalViewController:leaderBoardCont animated:YES];
    }
```

}

and then you should also implement the delegate method:

```
-(void) leaderboardViewControllerDidFinish:(GKLeaderboardViewController *)viewController {

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    viewController = nil;
}
```

Here 1S is the identifier for the leader board you created in iTunes Connect. Hope this helps.

**Edit**: since you are still having problems, check these tutorials out. They cover everything about leader boards and achievements.

[1st part](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk-game-center-achievements-and-leaderboards-part-1/)

[2nd part](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk-game-center-achievements-and-leaderboards-part-2/)

Answer (score 0):

You're sending the `presentModalViewController` message to an object that doesn't recognize it. So the class you wrote in your "Game.m" file doesn't inherit from `UIViewController`. Dunno what framework you're using, but you'll have to init a `UIViewController` instance to show the GameCenter view.